# $4$ or more type $2$ implies $3$ or less type $1$

Tags: inequality, logic, optimization, summation, mathematical-modeling

I'm having difficulties with the logic with the last part of the reformulation part of the problem below.

---

[image]

---

Let $x_i$ be the the number of ships of type $i$ to purchase.

---

For $4a:$ (the formulation)

$$\text{Min} \ z = 20,000x_1 + 1,000x_2$$

s.t.

1. 7500 soldiers

$$2,000x_1 + 1,000x_2 \le 7,500$$

2. 55,000 gallons

$$12,000x_1 + 7,000x_2 \le 55,000$$

3. 900 crew people (crewmen?)

$$250x_1 + 100x_2 \le 900$$

4. integer constraint for ships

$$x_1, x_2 \in \{0,1,2,...\}$$

---

For $4b:$ (the reformulation)

$$\text{Min} \ z = 20,000x_1 + 1,000x_2 \color{red}{+ 2,000y_1 + 1,000y_2}$$

s.t.

1. same
2. same
3. same
4. same
5. $$x_2 \le My_1, y_1 \in \{0,1\}$$
6. $$x_2 - 2 \le My_2, y_2 \in \{0,1\}$$

7.

I think we have to say, linearly, that:

1. if $x_2 \ge 4$, then $y_3 = 0$.
2. if $y_3 = 0$, then $x_1 \le 3$.

then say **exactly one** of the following (also linearly):

3. converse of 'if $x_2 \ge 4$, then $y_3 = 0$'
4. converse of 'if $y_3 = 0$, then $x_1 \le 3$'

and finally say

5. $y_3$ is binary.

I believe these translate to:

1. $$x_2 - 3 \le M(1-y_3)$$
2. $$x_1 - 3 \le M(y_3)$$
3. $$4 - x_2 \le My_3$$
4. $$4 - x_1 \le M(1-y_3)$$
5. $$y_3 \in \{0,1\}$$

Is that right? I think if I use $4$ instead of $3$, I'm going to get the contrapositive of $(iii)$.

Comment: Note that you need to transport all the soldiers, so the corresponding restriction has to be $2,000x_1 + 1,000x_2 \ge 7,500$.

Comment: @AugSB Thanks ^-^ How are the other things?