# Changing a model in to a mixed integer linear programing model

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

Trying to learn about integer programming in quarantine and I've come across a problem that stumped me. I searched the net but couldn't see anything similar and would appreciate another set of eyes on how to approach it.

> Turn the given model in to a binary mixed integer linear programing
> model:
>
> $\operatorname{Max} z=a(x)+2 b(y)$
>
> s.t $\quad x, y \geq 0$
>
> At minimum two thirds of the given constraints apply:
>
> $$2 x+y \leq 16, \quad x+y \leq 9, \quad x+3 y \leq 12$$
>
> $$a(x)=\begin{cases}10+3 x, & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 4$}, \\ 14+2 x, &\text{if $x \geq 4$},\end{cases} \quad 
> b(y)=\begin{cases}8+y, &\text{if $0 \leq y \leq 3$} \\ 2+3y, &\text{if  $y \geq 3$}\end{cases}$$

It hints to consider making use of multiple $x$ and $y$ variables and I know that if I want to try linearizing the problem I should go with $b(y)$ due to $y$ having a coefficient of $3$ in the third function.

Comment: It looks like $x$ and $y$ symbols are not consistent.

Comment: Thank you, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with four binary variables.  For $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, let binary variable $z_i$ indicate whether constraint $i$ is satisfied, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
2x+y-16&\le M_1(1-z_1)\\
x+y-9&\le M_2(1-z_2)\\
x+3y-12&\le M_3(1-z_3)\\
z_1+z_2+z_3&\ge 2
\end{align}
The original constraints imply upper bounds $x\le 9$ and $y\le 9$, so you can find good values for the $M_i$ constants based on that.  For example, take $M_1=2(9)+9-16=11$.

For $a(x)$, the piecewise linear function is concave, so the maximization objective means that you can replace $a(x)$ with a variable $u$ and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
u&\le 10+3x\\
u&\le 14+2x
\end{align}

For $b(y)$, the piecewise linear function is not concave. Replace $b(y)$ with a variable $v$, introduce a binary variable $z_4$ to indicate which segment is used, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
0z_4+3(1-z_4)\le y&\le 3z_4+9(1-z_4)\\
0\le v-(8+y)&\le M_4 z_4\\
0\le v-(2+3y)&\le M_5(1-z_4)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I don’t quite understand how binary variable z4 is introduced, could you expand on that section?

Comment: @Songaro His $z_4$ is my $\delta$: if $z_4=1$, then $y$ is in the interval $[0,3]$. And if $z_4=0$, then $y \in [3,9]$.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different ways to do this, there are different options [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749509/convert-a-piecewise-linear-non-convex-function-into-a-linear-optimisation-proble/1749655#1749655). Here is one, which is definitely not the best, but which is quite natural I guess.

I will only show you how to it for $a(x)$, the method is identical for $b(y)$.

Define a binary variable $\delta$ that takes value $1$ if and only if $x\le 4$:

$$
4(1-\delta)\le x \le 4 +M(1-\delta)
$$
$M$ is an upper bound on $x$. And then define the continuous variable $a$ as follows:

$$
a = (10+3x)\delta + (14+2x)(1-\delta)
$$

Now you have non linear terms (in $x\delta$) that you need to linearize, for example like [this](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-continuous-and-binary.html).

---

In practice, before using such transformations blindly, be sure to analyze the nature of the function: is it convex or concave, and are you maximizing or minimizing. As mentioned by Rob Pratt, if you are minimizing (maximizing) a convex (concave) function, a much simpler approach is available. Be sure to check his answer.

For the part where at least $2$ constraints out of $3$ should be satisfied, also please refer to @Rob Pratt's answer, as to my knowledge there is no other way to do it.

---

Just for pleasure, I also like this method:

Redefine $x$ in terms of new variables $x_1 \ge 0$ and $x_2 \ge 0$ as follows:
\begin{align}
x&=x_1+x_2+4(1-\delta)\\
x_1&\le 4 \delta \\
x_2& \le 5 (1-\delta)
\end{align}

So $x_1$ is the range on the first interval $[0,4]$, and $x_2$ on the second one $[4,9]$.
And so you can rewrite $a(x)$ linearly:
$$
a = 3x_1+10\delta +2x_2+22(1-\delta)
$$

Comment: Note also the part of the question about two thirds of the given constraints.

Comment: Yes I completely missed that. I will refer to your answer in mine (and upvote yours on the way)